# cocos2d create_project.py not working

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to create a new project on cocos2d in Win 8, but when I execute the create_proyect.py on the command prompt it seems to be skiping the parameters.

```
create_project.py -project randomName -package com.MyCompany.AwsomeGame -language cpp
```

The above command's result is the same as:

```
create_project.py
```

Comment: which version of cocos2d-x do you use? And did you install python?

Comment: I used v2.2.2, with pyton I tried v3.x, v2.7 and v2.6.
The create_project executes but it looks like it is ignorin the parameters

Comment: I haven't met this error. But python v2.7 works well with me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and Finally I solved the problem by using this command

```
$ python create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.MyCompany.AwesomeGame -language cpp
```